# Error inserting NOW into datetime returns "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Tags: sql, vbscript

I am using the INSERT statement below to insert NOW into a datetime field in a SQL dbase

```
<%
 varAlert = request.querystring("alertID")
 varInspector = session("stUserid")
 varDateRead = NOW 

dim sqlalerts

Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con.Open MM_inspections_STRING

sqlalerts = "INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_AlertsRead (alertID, inspectorID, dateread) VALUES ('"  & varAlert  & "' ,'"  & varInspector  & "','"  & varDateRead & "')"
con.Execute sqlalerts

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

%>
```

but it's returning :

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e07'

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

/html/admin/inspectorsAlertView.asp, line 25

line 25 is the execute statement, am at a loss, NOW returns a valid datetime, and the field 'dateread' is definitely a datetime field, and the above INSERT has worked dozens of times without a problem.

Comment: Why don't you just let your database insert the current date? Instead of passing a value from your front end, for that part of the insert statement use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `GetDate()`.

Comment: I need to insert it from the front end, because I need the field to stay NULL until the alert is read by the end user, and there are other datetime fields (that have GetDate() as default value) in the table that are inserted or updated before the end user gets to read the alert, and I dont want it to update the dateread field when the initial insert runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today is 13 November - in UK that would be written as 13/11/2012 but in US it would be 11/13/2012. i think you are inserting the date in the wrong format - which will mean that you are trying to use the 13th month.

I suspect that this worked before because your dates would have been valid, but incorrect values stored in your database. Check your database for previously inserted values.