# Insert Date And Time VB into Database Table

Tags: database, vb.net, date, time

I am using a DateTimePicker to select the date, and a TextBox that has the time.

I am trying to insert both values into a table, but it does not work

```
INSERT INTO dt (date) VALUES('" & DateTimePicker1.Text  & TextBox1.Text & "');
```

The `date` column is of `datetime` type.

The code is showing this error : conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Comment: What is the value of TextBox.Text? And if this is vb.net, why do you have a semicolon there?

Comment: The value of textbox is 12:50 , i copied the statement from the sql express thats why the semicolon is there

Comment: Please include the error you are getting in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to be passing datetimes as strings to your database owing to cultural differences in their representations. Instead, you can pass a datetime type by using a parameter. For SQL Server you need something along the lines of

```
Dim dt As DateTime
dt = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date ' use only the date portion '
Dim tim As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, tim) Then
    dt = dt + tim.TimeOfDay ' use only the time portion '
Else
    MsgBox("Could not understand the value in the time box. Using midnight.")
End If

Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO dt (date) VALUES (@DateTime)"

Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn)
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@DateTime", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = dt})
'TODO: ExecuteNonQuery
```

Comment: i added to the above code the connection and open connection but it didnt work, what should i add?

Comment: @Legend-Lb You'll need to show us the actual code you're using and expand on "it didn't work" - did you get an error message, nothing happened or...

Comment: +1. You are right, parameters are the ultimate solution. We always use them in production code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a space between the text of the two text boxes:

```
insert into dt (date) values('" & DateTimePicker1.Text & " " & TextBox1.Text & "')
```

Comment: Its showing an error , it says conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Answer (score 0):

Your date has to be formatted for a certain culture to be correctly inserted into a database. Or just use culture neutral strings, such as `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Your first step is to create a DateTime from `DateTimePicker1.Text` and `TextBox1.Text` - you can use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx). Then format your DateTime as `.ToString("G")` - check this article on MSDN for more standard formats: [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Similar problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13358665/897326).